# Application.Restart() with CommandLine Arguments

Tags: c#, application-restart

I have an application that gets passed command line arguments. After a certain amount of time I want to restart my application, passing it the same command line arguments from the first time the application was started.

```
private void frmSetTime_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] cmds = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        //Here i gets Command Line Arguments
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.show(ex.message);
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}

public void ExecuteLogic(Object obj)
{
    try
    {
        //My set of Statements
        Therad.sleep(5000);
        ExecuteLogic(obj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.show(ex.message);
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
        ApplicationRestart();
    }
}

private void ApplicationRestart()
{
    try
    {
        if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 >= 10000000)
        {                         
            Application.Restart();                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will happen automatically.  You don't need to change anything.

From the docs of [Application.Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx):

> If your application was originally supplied command-line options when it first executed, Restart will launch the application again with the same options.

Comment: I have a Form Closed event also is this affecting because my Application Exits but not start again.

Comment: Hi All,

I gets the Solution. It Works with the Form_closed event i just add 

private void ApplicationRestart()
{
    try
    {
        if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 >= 10000000)
        {     
            Form1.FormClosed -= new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);                    
            Application.Restart();                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
    }
}

Also Do not forgot to Kill the process in Form_closed Event.

Thanks For your Help.